# How to return string(variable value) from page object to test file in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I am practicing page object model in nightwatch but I am unable to return variable optionSelected value from page object to test. I have two pages: googleAdvanceSearch page where i have written locators to select options eg-what to search,result shud be of past month,country,language etc and result page where I am verifying if result is according to option selected.

googleAdvanceSearch Page code:

```
module.exports= {
  url:"https://www.google.co.in/advanced_search",
  elements: {
    input :"input[name='as_q']",
    languageBox :"#lr_button",
    regionButton :"#cr_button",
    lastUpdateBtn :"#as_qdr_button",
    searchButton :"input[value='Advanced Search']",
  },
  commands: [
    {
      setQuery: function(value) {
        return this.setValue('@input',value);
      },
      selectFilter: function(selector,value) {
        return this
                  .click(selector)
                  .click(`li[value="${value}"]`);
      },
       selectAndStoreOption: function(selector,value) {
              var optionSelected;
              this.click(selector)
                  .getText(`li[value='${value}']`,function(result){
                      optionSelected=result.value;
                    })
                  .click(`li[value="${value}"]`)  
                  return optionSelected;            //Can we return like this?
      },
      clickSubmit: function() {
        return this.click('@searchButton');
      }    
    }
  ]
}
```

In selectAndStoreOption function, I am trying to save text 'upto a month ago' of 'm' option (.getText(`li[value='${value}']`) selected in a variable optionSelected.

Result page code :

```
module.exports= {
  elements: {
      monthBox : "div[class='hdtb-mn-hd EISXeb']"
  },
  commands: [
  {
      verifyCorrectResultDisplayed: function(optionSelected,textToSearch) {
       this
       .assert.urlContains("as_q=Elon+Musk","Elon Musk searched")
       .assert.urlContains("lr=lang_pl","Language polish set")
       .assert.visible(`input[title='Search'][value='${textToSearch}']`,"Search result visible on UI");
      
       this.getText('@monthBox',function(result) {
       if(optionSelected=="upto a month ago") {              **//optionSelected is undefined**
         this.assert.containsText('@monthBox',"Past month","Past month result displayed");   **//This assertion not printing**
        }
      })
     return this;
      }
    }
     ]
}
```

Here I am checking if optionSelected variable value is "upto a month ago" then my result should contain Past month text. But this assertion is not working as optionSelected value is undefined.

Test:

```
module.exports= {
  "@tags":["google"],
  before : function(browser) {
    let googleSearchPage=browser.page.googleSearchPage();
    googleSearchPage.navigate();
    browser.windowMaximize();
  },
  "Google Advanced Search Test": function(browser) {
     var googleSearchPage=browser.page.googleSearchPage();
     var resultPage=browser.page.resultPage();
     var data=browser.globals;
     googleSearchPage
                    .setQuery(data.googleAdvancedSearch.textToSearch)
                    .selectFilter('@languageBox','lang_pl')
                    .selectFilter('@regionButton','countryPH');
      var optionSelec= googleSearchPage.selectAndStoreOption('@lastUpdateBtn','m');
       console.log(optionSelec);
      googleSearchPage.clickSubmit();
      resultPage
                .verifyCorrectResultDisplayed(optionSelec,data.googleAdvancedSearch.textToSearch);
  },
  after : function(browser) {
    browser
           .saveScreenshot('tests_output/google.png')
           .end();
  }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You must be aware of javascript being executed synchronously, which may result in your code being executed not necessarily in the same order as it is written somewhat.
For that reason, I suggest you to make your "Google Advanced Search Test" function asynchronous like so:

```
asynch function (browser) {
....
}
```

Then it will allow you to await for your actions on googleSearchPage like so:

```
var optionSelect = await googleSearchPage
                    .setQuery(data.googleAdvancedSearch.textToSearch)
                    .selectFilter('@languageBox','lang_pl')
                    .selectFilter('@regionButton','countryPH');
                    .selectAndStoreOption('@lastUpdateBtn','m');
console.log(optionSelec);
```